# Magento products showing on specific store view that are not enabled on

Tags: magento2, search

I have 2 store views (Bahrain Store & Saudi Arabia Store, Some products are only enable in Bahrain store, but when browsing in Saudi Arabia store those products are shown still in the search bar, but when I click on them it redirects to the search page results

For example; I searched for this product https://prnt.sc/1qtpmu6 which is only enabled for Bahrain store view and when I clicked on it, it redirected to this result page https://prnt.sc/1qtpp7e

Product website in admin panel https://prnt.sc/1qtpr93

Answer (score 0):

Generally this types of bug happen for the following reasons :

1. Cache was not handled and store ID key/identity  was not used while cache was saved.
2. Some module was developed ignoring multistore concept.
   Disable plugins and check